# Web API Json Response

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing Web API for my client. They have suggestion that all response should be a common JSON structure.

```
{ Data:"", Status:true, Message:"" }
```

If error means

```
{ Error:"", Status:false, Message:"" }
```

Which is the best method to create a common JSON structure as returns.
Now I created a class having these properties. And created 2 classes from IHttpActionResult,Error.cs and Success.cs, From that the response is created and returned from the controller.

The thing is in my controller,

```
public IHttpActionResult GetNewsAndAnnouncements()
    {
        var data = newsAndAnnouncementsDataServices.NewsAndAnnouncements();
        if (data != null && data.Count() > 0)
        {
            return new Success(Request, "News and Announcements Retrieved Successfully", data);
        }
        return new Error(Request, "No News and Announcements Found");
    }
```

Error.cs

```
public class Error : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private IErrorResponseModel errorResponse;

    public Error(HttpRequestMessage request, string message)
    {
        _message = message;
        _request = request;
        errorResponse = new ErrorResponseModel();
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        errorResponse.Message = _message;
        errorResponse.Status = false;
        errorResponse.Error = _message;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<object>(errorResponse, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Success.cs

```
public class Success : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string _message;
    private readonly object _data;
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private IDataResponseModel dataResponse = new DataResponseModel();
    public Success(HttpRequestMessage request, string message, object data)
    {
        _message = message;
        _request = request;
        _data = data;
    } 
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        dataResponse.Message = _message;
        dataResponse.Status = true;
        dataResponse.Data = _data;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<object>(dataResponse, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
            RequestMessage = _request
        };
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

DataResponseModel.cs

```
public class DataResponseModel : Mobility.Common.IDataResponseModel 
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

ErrorResponseModel.cs

```
public class ErrorResponseModel : Mobility.Common.IErrorResponseModel
{
    public object Error { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a right method. I need suggestion. Is there any other way to achieve this. I heard about delegating handler something. But I don't have much idea on these. 
Please help me.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable implementation to me.

Comment: Why don't return `Ok(dataResponse)` or `BadRequest(errorResponse)`?

Comment: @Dennis. From where? From Controller or Success.cs.
In BadRequest() we can return only a string or Modelstatedictionry. I want to return a model.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is to hook into the ASP.NET pipeline using custom handlers to build a common response object.
For instance:

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Version { get { return "1.2.3"; } }

  [DataMember]
  public int StatusCode { get; set; }

  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  public object Result { get; set; }

  public ApiResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, object result = null, string   errorMessage = null)
  {
      StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
      Result = result;
      ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
  }
}
```

Have a look at this post for a reference implementation http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information